# CampaignName CONTAINS_ALL ['test', 'play'] Invalid or inapplicable operator is used for field CampaignName

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I have followed the syntax from this [doc](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_campaignselector)

```
withCondition("ColumnName IN [Value1, Value2]")
```

But I get an error when running this piece of code:

```
  var adGroups = AdsApp
    .adGroups()
    .withCondition(agName)
    .withCondition(campName)
    .get();
```

Error:

```
5/25/2021 9:32:53 PM    CampaignName CONTAINS_ALL ['test', 'play']
5/25/2021 9:32:54 PM    Invalid or inapplicable operator is used for field CampaignName. Please check the supported operators. (file Code.gs, line 52)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CampaignName is of string values, so it can use a chained `CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE`condition.